# How to allow blender to only use part of your CPU computing power?

Tags: 3d-view, performance

Is there a way to only allow blender to use part of my computing power?  For example, I don't want blender to use more than 25% of my CPU computing power.  Please make sure that it doesn't shut off when you use too much computing power but instead just keeps on running at 25% computing power.  Too clarify, I don't need this for rendering, I want it be for the 3d-view.

Comment: please clarify: do you mean that you are rendering and at the same time you would like to continue using Blender for modeling etc?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/214566/are-there-solutions-that-can-limit-the-cpu-usage-of-a-process might answer your question

Comment: @Bruno just for modeling

Answer (score 1):

Under render > Performance >Threads,
set it to fixed and you can chose how many **Cores** Blender can use when rendering in cycles. Not sure for Eevee. This should also work for modeling

[image: ...]

Also you can use Cpu affinity which limits how mnay core blender uses as a whole through

Task manager> Details>Blender.exe (Might be different I use .zip) > right click > Set affinity  ,  on windows

or using what is discussed here for Ubuntu [Link to Ubuntu forums](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102258/how-to-set-cpu-affinity-to-a-process)

Note: For this to work you will have to make sure the amount of threads in performance is the same as the amount of cores as you have set in the affinity, or it will be reset every time you go into rendered view or render.